# Error on processing files in a directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, io

I have a directory with images that I have to check.
My code is

```
import imghdr as ih
import os

path = 'path_to_dir'

def check_format(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        format = ih.what(file)
        print(format)
        if format != 'jpeg' and format != 'png':
            print("format error...\n")
            return -1
    return 0
```

I execute and I have this error:

... line 14, in what f = open(file, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'world_cup.jpg'

but the file `world_cup.jpg` is a file in the directory.

Comment: try opening `os.path.join(path, file)` instead of just `file`

Comment: You aren't in the directory.  You can fix this a number of ways. 1. Use `glob`, 2. `open(os.path.join(path, file))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    format = ih.what(file)
```

into:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    format = ih.what(os.path.join(path, file))
```